# How to store variant data in C++

Tags: c++, variant

I'm in the process of creating a class that stores metadata about a particular data source.  The metadata is structured in a tree, very similar to how XML is structured.  The metadata values can be integer, decimal, or string values.

I'm curious if there is a good way in C++ to store variant data for a situation like this.  I'd like for the variant to use standard libraries, so I'm avoiding the COM, Ole, and SQL VARIANT types that are available.

My current solution looks something like this:

```
enum MetaValueType
{
    MetaChar,
    MetaString,
    MetaShort,
    MetaInt,
    MetaFloat,
    MetaDouble
};

union MetaUnion
{
    char cValue;
    short sValue;
    int iValue;
    float fValue;
    double dValue;
};

class MetaValue
{
...
private:
    MetaValueType ValueType;
    std::string StringValue;
    MetaUnion VariantValue;
};
```

The MetaValue class has various Get functions for obtaining the currently stored variant value, but it ends up making every query for a value a big block of if/else if statements to figure out which value I'm looking for.

I've also explored storing the value as only a string, and performing conversions to get different variant types out, but as far as I've seen this leads to a bunch of internal string parsing and error handling which isn't pretty, opens up a big old can of precision and data loss issues with floating point values, and still doesn't eliminate the query if/else if issue stated above.

Has anybody implemented or seen something that's cleaner to use for a C++ variant data type using standard libraries?

Comment: Might I suggest phrasing your title as a descriptive question?  Perhaps something like "How to store variant data in C++?"  I think you'll get more responses!

Comment: Hmm … I understood the title at once.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of C++17, there’s [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

If you can’t use that yet, you might want [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/variant.html). A similar, but distinct, type for modelling polymorphism is provided by [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (and, pre-C++17, [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/any.html)).

Just as an additional pointer, you can look for “[type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450159/1968)”.

Comment: Herb Sutter suggests this answer as well: http://herbsutter.com/2008/06/20/type-inference-vs-staticdynamic-typing/

Answer (score 13):

While Konrad's answer (using an existing standardized solution) is certainly preferable to writing your own bug-prone version, the boost variant has some overheads, especially in copy construction and memory.

A common customized approach is the following modified Factory Pattern:

1. Create a Base interface for a generic object that also encapsulates the object type (either as an enum), or using 'typeid' (preferable).
2. Now implement the interface using a template `Derived` class.
3. Create a factory class with a templateized `create` function with signature:

`template <typename _T> Base * Factory::create ();`

This internally creates a `Derived<_T>` object on the heap, and retuns a dynamic cast pointer. Specialize this for each class you want implemented.

Finally, define a `Variant` wrapper that contains this `Base *` pointer and defines template get and set functions. Utility functions like `getType()`, `isEmpty()`, assignment and equality operators, etc can be appropriately implemented here.

Depending on the utility functions and the factory implementation, supported classes will need to support some basic functions like assignment or copy construction.

Comment: Again, if you can, please use the boost classes, unless microsecond-level timing is important to you.

Comment: FIFY: nanosecond-level.

Comment: :) nanosecond per API use - in my experience, a fundamental implementation like this adds up.

Answer (score 9):

You can also go down to a more C-ish solution, which would have a void* the size of a double on your system, plus an enum for which type you're using. It's reasonably clean, but definitely a solution for someone who feels wholly comfortable with the raw bytes of the system.

Comment: void * is pretty evil. Prefer more elegant solutions when possible.

Comment: It's a very elegant solution...if you are comfortable working with raw memory.

Comment: I don't agree that void pointers are elegant. You are bypassing the type system, its not a matter of being comfortable working with raw memory, its a matter of getting all the help from the compiler that you possible can.

Comment: It's OK to bypass the type system if you know what you're doing. C++/C are not 100% typed anyway.

Comment: For C `++`, void* pointers are pure evil. With all the disadvantages of raw pointers, you think you can't get worse. It turns out you can...
1. it bypasses type-checking. Even with enums (e.g. `if (myType == MY_CLASS) { MYCLASS* val = (MYCLASS*)(voidPtr); }`, a polymorphic MYCLASS is gonna wreak havoc with memory. Using a base class pointer and dynamic casts is marginally better.
2. possibility of splice-deleting (and no way to check).
3. the 'double' solution suggested suffers from endian-dependency.

Comment: @Fox When you want to have typesafety then you have to use java than c or c++. Most times there are better options than using void * pointers. But it defently make sense to take a look at all options. Using void * pointers would also boost your skills. Because you make a lot of mistakes and lern to solve them. :)

Comment: that's like saying Uganda's laws are inconsistent and have loopholes, so it's lawless and I'm justified commiting murders there. Granted C/C++'s type-system is not fool-proof, and using pointers, C-style typecasts and reinterpret_cast can allow you to get around. That doesn't mean you toss every rule/recommendation out of the window. (No offense to Ugandans - it's an example)

Comment: To quiet the C++ void * nazis, just use char * instead of void *. They are the same size (check this).

Answer (score 7):

C++17 now has `std::variant` which is exactly what you're looking for.

[std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

> The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union. An
> instance of std::variant at any given time either holds a value of one
> of its alternative types, or in the case of error - no value (this
> state is hard to achieve, see valueless_by_exception).
>
> As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type T, the
> object representation of T is allocated directly within the object
> representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to
> allocate additional (dynamic) memory.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question had been answered for a long time, for the record I would like to mention that [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) in the Qt libraries also does this.

> Because C++ forbids unions from including types that have non-default
> constructors or destructors, most interesting Qt classes cannot be
> used in unions. Without QVariant, this would be a problem for
> QObject::property() and for database work, etc.
>
> A QVariant object holds a single value of a single type() at a time.
> (Some type()s are multi-valued, for example a string list.) You can
> find out what type, T, the variant holds, convert it to a different
> type using convert(), get its value using one of the toT() functions
> (e.g., toSize()) and check whether the type can be converted to a
> particular type using canConvert().