# Static CRTP class without knowing derived type?

Tags: c++, templates, static, crtp

Given the following, working code.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Detail>
class AbstractLogger
{
public:
    static void log(const char* str) {
        Detail::log_detailled(str);
    }
};

class Logger : public AbstractLogger<Logger>
{
public:
    static void log_detailled(const char* str) {
        std::cerr << str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    AbstractLogger<Logger>::log("main function running!");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to put `AbstractLogger` into a library, and let the library user define his own logger, like the `Logger` class here. This has one drawback: `AbstractLogger<Logger>` can not be used inside the library, since the library can not know `Logger`.

Notes:

- Please no virtual functions or questions why not. Also, I am aware of the similar problem that "static virtual" members are invalid. Maybe, there is a workaround in CRTP :)
- C++11 will be interesting, however, I need "usual" C++.

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to put `AbstractLogger` into a library*. Do you mean you want to *use* it in the library without knowing the instantiating type? Or do you want some sort of generated code to be in the library? or...?

Comment: Smells like a heavy design flaw and abuse of the CRT pattern ...

Comment: Templates are compiled into concrete class representations when they are defined in code. If you define an `AbstractLogger<Class1>` and an `AbstractLogger<Class2>`, two versions will be compiled. In a library, you have to define what is available beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to code against a concept, while providing helpers so that users may easily produce types that satisfy one or more of those concepts. As an example, something like `boost::iterator_facade` is a CRTP helper that makes it easier for a user to write an iterator. Then, that iterator can be used anywhere an iterator is accepted -- for instance in the range constructor of `std::vector`. Notice how that particular constructor has no foreknowledge of the user-defined type.

In your case, `AbstractLogger` would be the CRTP helper. The missing piece would be to define e.g. a logger concept. As a result, notice that everything that needs a logger either needs to be implemented as a template or you need a type-erasing container to hold arbitrary loggers.

Concept checks (like those provided by [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)) are convenient for this kind of programming, since they allow to represent a concept with actual code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please outline shortly how such a "type erasing container" could look like?

Comment: @Johannes It would be very similar to `std::function<R(A...)>`, which is a container for anything that is Callable with signature `R(A...)`. So it would have a constructor `template<typename Logger> container(Logger log);` taking anything conforming to a logger, and would itself conform to the Logger concept -- delegating actual operations to the logger that was passed at construction time. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques) outlines some type-erasure techniques.

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is that you want to have a library that uses this as a logging mechanism without knowing the exact instantiating type, I would advice against it.

The only way of doing it while meeting your other requirements (i.e. no virtual functions) is that all your functions/types in the library that need to log are converted into templates that take the `Logger` type. The net result is that most of your interface becomes a template (although you can probably move a good amount of the implementation to non-templated code, it will make your life much harder than needed, and it will still generate a much larger binary).

If your concern with virtual functions is performance, then you should reconsider your approach and the problems it brings. In particular, logging **is** expensive. Most logging libraries tackle it by optimizing the non-logging case (by means of macros that avoid calling the logger if the log level/group/... are not enabled), but still leave dynamic dispatch for the actual writting. The cost of the dynamic dispatch is negligible compared with the cost of writing to the console, or a file, or even with the cost of generating the message that will be logged (I am assuming that you not only log literal strings)

Answer (score 0):

Template classes can't be 'put in a library' since they are instantiated by the compiler as specializations of their template parameters.

You may put parameter independent stuff used in the template implementation into a library though.