# QVariant vs boost::any vs boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, qvariant, boost-any

I need efficient way to store values of different types (int, float, QString or std::string, bool) in one of "generic" containers like QVariant.

I want to archive less memory usage.

I prefer a container that doesn't store type of the internal value because it is an overhead.

Which one should I use?

Comment: If you really want a container that does not store the type of the internal value, you could use `std::unique_ptr<void>`. But an object of such a type means "I reference some important data which you no longer know how to read", so it seems pretty pointless to me.

Comment: But can we check the type of any object with `typeid` instruction, can't we?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev the major requirement is that the use of `typeid` implicitly means that you must have `RTTI` enabled. Also this kind of solutions rely on `c++ type erasure` techniques and I don't know how much this will influence the ability of your `RTTI` in giving you the right answer. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques

Comment: As it says [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), `typeid` only works the way you want if you use polymorphism. If you use `typeid` on a `void` pointer, it will return you `void*`, if you use it on a dereferenced `void` pointer, the program should not compile because you are not allowed to dereference a `void` pointer. Furthermore, even if it worked the way you want, the libraries you proposed probably would be implemented using the `typeid` operator.

Comment: I guess simple union can satisfy my requirements.

Comment: @tmporaries you are basically an hair away from the _"undefined behaviour theme park"_; with both an `union` and `void pointers`, it's extremely easy to get an UB, at the point that this kind of operations are really useful if you really know what you are doing. If you need space use a compression algorithm on what you have in memory and keep things simple.

Comment: try mine, though it does store the type, no RTTI or allocations though :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28939/movable-and-copyable-variant

Answer (score 3):

`boost::any` can hold values of any type, but you have to know what it can possibly hold to be able to extract the value and it allocates memory on the heap for the stored value.

`boost::variant` on the other hand, can only store values of a set of specified types and you can easily find out what it holds, the `sizeof` of `boost::variant` is going to be the `sizeof` of the largest value type it contains + some extra for the type of the stored value because it does not use heap memory (unless a recursive variant is used).

From memory usage standpoint of view `boost::variant` may be more efficient because it does not use heap memory. Also, `boost::variant` is more type-safe that `boost::any`, the compiler can find more errors at compile time for you.

Answer (score -1):

I've faced similar question about a year ago. I don't remember the reasoning but I've gone with the boost:any. boost:any does store the typeid that can be used to retrieve the value in desire format.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    boost::any value;

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            value = (double) 8.05;
            break;
        case 1:
            value = (int) 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            //std::string str = "Hello any world!";
            //value = str;
            value = std::string("Hello any world!");
            break;
        }

        if(value.type() == typeid(double))
            std::cout << "it's double type: " << boost::any_cast<double>(value) << std::endl;
        else if(value.type() == typeid(int))
            std::cout << "it's int type: " << boost::any_cast<int>(value) << std::endl;
        else if(value.type() == typeid(std::string))
            std::cout << "it's string type: " << boost::any_cast<std::string>(value) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!!