# What is the virtual function inside of shared_ptr's Control Block?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've read an "Item" about **shared_ptr** in Scott Meyers' book "Effective Modern C++" where he says the following:

> The usual control block implementation is more
>   sophisticated than you might expect. It makes use of inheritance, and ***there’s even a virtual function. (It’s used to ensure that the pointed-to object is properly destroyed.)***
>   That means that using std::shared_ptrs also incurs the cost of the machinery for the virtual function used by the control block.

Then he doesn't explain what a virtual function does exactly. As far as I know, the proper way of deleting a pointed object is using deleters or type erasure. So, please explain what this is about.

Comment: Or he gave a name of "virtual function" to the "type erasure" mechanism?

Comment: [Type-erasing the deleter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5450159/2756719) requires the use of virtual functions. (Well, technically it doesn't require it, but that's the most convenient way to implement it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual function is required to ensure the object being shared is appropriately deleted. Unlike a `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` does not require full knowledge of the type when its template is instantiated. E.g. you can do this:

```
class Foo;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = make_foo();
```

Note that in the code above we don't have the complete Foo type, just the forward declaration. If we let `foo` go out of scope, the object it is pointing to will be correctly deleted because when `Foo` was created in `make_foo`, a deleter was also created which knows the complete type of `Foo`, and hence can call the appropriate destructors. (E.g. Perhaps `make_foo` creates a `Bar` that inherits from `Foo` and returns that. `shared_ptr`'s will handle this fine.)

The function on the deleter object that `shared_ptr` creates to manage the deletion of `Foo` will be virtual, allowing `shared_ptr` to call the correct destructor.

Roughly this could be something like this:

```
struct deleter_interface {
    virtual void ~deleter_interface = default;
    virtual void dispose() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct deleter : deleter_interface {
    T* ptr_;
    deleter(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
    virtual void dispose() { delete ptr_; }
};

template <typename T>
shared_ptr {
    T* ptr_;
    deleter_interface* deleter_;
    ...
};

template <typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr<T>(T* ptr)
    : ptr_(ptr), deleter_(new deleter<T>(ptr)) {}

template <typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr<T>() { deleter_->dispose(); delete deleter_; }
```

While this seems more complicated that is strictly necessary, it is to allow `shared_ptr` to be used without the complete type. For example what if you wanted to do this:

In a.h:

```
struct Foo;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> a = make_object();
// ... let a go out of scope
```

And in a.cc:

```
struct Foo { ... };
struct Bar : Foo { ... };
std::shared_ptr<Foo> make_object() { return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Bar); }
```

If we didn't have the virtual function used in the deleter code, then `Bar` would not be destructed correctly. With the virtual function it doesn't matter that the header (a.h) never sees the definition of `Foo` or `Bar`.

Comment: hm... I think there is no way to create a `deleter_interface`  object cuz it has a pure virtual function. And how `deleter_`  finds out the type ? We can implement this behavour without a virtual function.

Comment: Yep. I rushed writing the code too quickly. I've updated so it actually works. This behaviour could be done without a virtual function, but only if you always had the complete type whenever you instantiated the shared_ptr. I'll add some extra explanation to the answer.

Comment: I mean we could have a template constructor, that receives another type's arg. e.g:
`template <class T>
class Shared
{

template <class U>
Shared(U* ptr):deleter<U>(ptr) ; //now deleter knows actual type of ptr 

`
But you revealed me another one way to implement this :) Thank you!
P.S. What about if I want to pass my deleter?

Comment: You could, but you'd still need the virtual function in the deleter as the instantiation of the shared_ptr destructor will not see the original type.

Comment: Why will it not see original type?  Lest consider the following instantiation  `Shared<Base> ptr (new Derived());` . Here constructor receives `Derived*` hence `U` is deduced to be `Derived` and `deleter<U>` instantiates as `deleter<Derived>` . So,**shared_ptr's destructor** doesn't know the original type, but **deleter does**