# What is type erasure in C++?

Tags: c++, type-erasure

So I was reading [this article about type erasure](https://davekilian.com/2014/10/24/cpp-type-erasure.html). But the code in that article seems partially incorrect, for example:

[Repaired link](http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html)

```
template <typename T>
class AnimalWrapper : public MyAnimal
{
    const T &m_animal;

public:
    AnimalWrapper(const T &animal)
        : m_animal(animal)
    { }

    const char *see() const { return m_animal.see(); }
    const char *say() const { return m_animal.say(); }
};
```

followed by

```
void pullTheString()
{
    MyAnimal *animals[] = 
    {
        new AnimalWrapper(Cow()), /* oO , isn't template argument missing? */
        ....
    };
}
```

These mistakes discouraged me from reading any further in the article.

Anyways; can anyone please teach what type erasure in C++ means, with simple examples?

I wanted to learn about it to understand how `std::function` works, but couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques

Comment: You either need to pass `<T>`, or use a function that deduces `T` and passes `<T>`.  Ie, `template<class T> MyAnimal* WrapAnimal(T const& t){return new AnimalWrapper<T>(t);}`, and replace `new AnimalWrapper` with `WrapAnimal`.

Comment: @NathanOliver In that question OP knows basic concepts of type erasure already.

Comment: I don't see the mistake.  Won't the template argument simply be deduced?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Sir, This is not the case with class templates, constructors don't deduce template arguments for class templates AFAIK.

Comment: @AngelusMortis:  Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AngelusMortis: They do—as of C++17.

Comment: It seems this guys blog is responsible for more than one of us being confused by his dodgy code which produces UB. I also was caught out, and posted this question just minutes before finding this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798271/c-is-passing-a-tempoary-object-to-a-class-holding-a-reference-to-that-object-v

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of type erasure in action:

```
// Type erasure side of things

class TypeErasedHolder
{
  struct TypeKeeperBase
  {
    virtual ~TypeKeeperBase() {}
  };

  template <class ErasedType>
  struct TypeKeeper : TypeKeeperBase
  {
    ErasedType storedObject;

    TypeKeeper(ErasedType&& object) : storedObject(std::move(object)) {}
  };

  std::unique_ptr<TypeKeeperBase> held;

public:
  template <class ErasedType>
  TypeErasedHolder(ErasedType objectToStore) : held(new TypeKeeper<ErasedType>(std::move(objectToStore)))
  {}
};

// Client code side of things

struct A
{
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destroyed an A\n"; }
};

struct B
{
  ~B() { std::cout << "Destroyed a B\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  TypeErasedHolder holders[] = { A(), A(), B(), A() };
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b357f0c8ec137b8)

As you can see, `TypeErasedHolder` can store objects of an arbitrary type, and destruct them correctly. The important point is that it does not impose any restrictions on the types supported<sup>(1)</sup>: they don't have to derive from a common base, for example.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Except for being movable, of course.

Comment: Hm, why aren’t you using ``&&`` (universal reference(?)) for the constructor argument of ``TypeErasedHolder`` and ``std::forward`` to pass it on to the ``TypeKeeper``? (trying to understand here, it seems you’re always taking a copy and then moving from that copy instead of moving the original object)

Comment: @JonasWielicki To keep the "very simple" aspect of the example. Using a forwarding reference would also require using `std::remove_reference` for the template argument to `TypeKeeper`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @AngelusMortis There is no forwarding reference (formerly known as "universal referene") in the code now, just a plain old rvalue reference. But if you'd prefer, I can remove that too (or just get rid of moving altogether, and rely on plain old `const&` and copy).

Comment: @Angew That's awesome, and thanks for treating noobies like me so nicely :)

Comment: (2) except being destroyable, of course.  As an aside, the movable requirement is easy to fix: add emplace based construction.  `template<class T> struct emplace_as_t{}; template<class T> emplace_as_t<T> emplace_as = {};` then add ctor `template<class T, class...Args> TypeErasedHolder(emplace_as_t<T>, Args&&...args)` etc.  But that isn't basic type erasure.