# C++ A function that can return one of two types depending on the accepted value

Tags: c++, function

```
fun(int a) {
    if (a) return a; return "empty";
}
```

I need a function that gets a number and depending on which number it is returns either an int variable or a string.
Please tell me how I can implement such a function.

Comment: You must specify a single return type therefore you could specify a type that can represent multiple types and could try researching [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815513/what-is-type-erasure-in-c).

Comment: That's an unusual requirement, but you could return a union of the two types, or, with the latest version of C++, use `std::variant`.

Comment: How would you use it?

Comment: You cannot. Because a function declaration should specify its return type at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

With C++ 17 you can use [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
std::variant<int, std::string> fun(int a) {
  if (a) return a; return "empty";
}
```

Or use a struct with [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
struct r {
  std::optional<int> i;
  std::optional<std::string> s;
};

r fun(int a) {
  r out;
  if (a) out.i = a; else out.s = "empty";
  return out;
}
```

Or for prior standards use a struct with fields indicating validity.

```
struct r {
  enum class type {i, s};
  int i;
  std::string s;
  type t;
};

r fun(int a) {
  r out;
  if (a) {
    out.i = a;
    out.t = r::type::i;
  else {
    out.s = "empty";
    out.t = r::type::s;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this flow with exceptions! If `func` is expecting to work with a number that is greater than 5, for example, you could do something like:

```
int func(int a) {
    if (a > 5) { return a; }
    throw std::runtime_error("Empty");
}

int main() {
    try {
        int x = func(3);
        // Do some stuff with x...
    } catch(const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Looks like the num is " << e.what();
    }
}
```

So you either process the `int` if things went well, or, if something bad happened, you grab the string from the exception and deal with it.

Comment: I don't see anything that returns `"empty"`. This answer is a guess that returning a string is supposed to have something to do with error propagation, but the question doesn't ask for that.

Comment: @Pete exceptions don't have to be used for error propagation, though I guess my strings aren't helping. I've edited to try to get away from that. OP wants a function that checks the input and acts on the input if the check passes. Otherwise, they want a string to be propagated back to the caller. This sounds like a perfect use of exceptions to me.

Comment: While it's technically true that "exceptions don't have to be used for error propagation", the overhead they impose means that they are, **in fact**, used only for error propagation. And that's what they were designed for; they are not intended to be an alternative return mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret-able languages like python does not have restrictions on type of argument and type of return value. However, C++ can only accept and return values of pre-defined type. 
Now, Adding to other answers, if you don't have C++17, You could try it this way:

```
std::pair<int, string> func(int a)
{
   if(a) return std::make_pair(a , "");
   return std::make_pair(0,"string");    
}
```

In callee, you can check for non-null against both members of std::pair.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by splitting the two different tasks into separate functions and continue your execution from there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;int inputValue = 0;

int returnInt() {
    std::cout << "Returning your int" << std::endl;
    return inputValue;
}

string returnString() {
    std::cout << "Returning your string" << std::endl;
    return "Your string";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please type in a number" << "\t";
    std::cin >> inputValue;
    if (inputValue > 5) {
        returnInt();
    }
    else {
        returnString();
    }
}
```