# Why is type checking not happening for std::function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, c++17, std-function

```
#include <functional>

void toggleOk(bool& b) { b = !b; }
void toggleBroken(bool b) { b = !b; }
void toggleInt(int i) { i = !i; }
void tooManyParams(bool b, int i) { i = !b; }

int main()
{
    typedef std::function<void(bool&)> CallbackType;
    typedef std::function<void(bool)> WrongCallbackType;

    CallbackType cb1 = [](bool b) { b = !b; }; // Should throw error - missing reference
    CallbackType cb2 = toggleOk; // Ok

    CallbackType cb3 = toggleBroken; // Should throw error - missing reference
    CallbackType cb4 = toggleInt; // Should throw error - integer instead of bool

    WrongCallbackType cb5 = toggleBroken; // Ok

    CallbackType cb6 = cb5; // Type checking not even applying between std::functions

    CallbackType cb7 = tooManyParams; // Only this statement throws error

    return 0;
}
```

Consider the above example, which is creating a bunch of callbacks that have **reference** to `bool` as a parameter. Except the very last callback `cb7`, this code can compile and run just fine, even though most of the functions stored in the callback objects mismatch the **reference** or **type** of the parameter.

I've encountered this behavior with VS19/C++20 with the lambda stored in the `std::function`, however I've tried this example with two distinct G++ compilers for Windows, with extra diagnostics enabled and with C++17/C++2a and none reported even a warning.

My question is - is this an expected behavior or is it a bug? Why?

Comment: The check is roughly: `bool b{}; toggleInt(b);`, and that compiles (except for `tooManyParams`).

Comment: The way I see it is you make a std::function which you pass a ref parameter, which then calls an underlying function without the ref. This is fine the ref won't be changed and all is still good. I checked at runtime if you call cb1, cb2 etc.. the behavior exactly as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is defined behavior from `std::function`

The `std::function` uses a [type erasure mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815513/what-is-type-erasure-in-c) to warp almost all kinds of callable objects, and parameterized to the non-const, non-ref non-volatile arguments and the return type of the callable.

You need to use plane typed function pointer to get the expected errors in the code

```
void toggleOk(bool& b) { b = !b; }
void toggleBroken(bool b) { b = !b; }
void toggleInt(int i) { i = !i; }
void tooManyParams(bool b, int i) { i = !b; }

int main()
{
    // typedef std::function<void(bool&)> CallbackType;
    // typedef std::function<void(bool)> WrongCallbackType;
    using CallbackType = void(*)(bool&);
    using WrongCallbackType = void(*)(bool);
    CallbackType cb1 = [](bool b) { b = !b; }; // error 

    CallbackType cb2 = toggleOk; // Ok

    CallbackType cb3 = toggleBroken; // error 
    CallbackType cb4 = toggleInt; // error

    WrongCallbackType cb5 = toggleBroken; // Ok
    CallbackType cb6 = cb5; // error

    return 0;
}
```

Now in the above `CallbackType` and `WrongCallbackType` are different types, and will produce the error as you expected.

However, you can only use the function pointer type (as shown above) in the case of lambda, only if [it is stateless (do not capture anything)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer).

Comment: I kind of wonder why this behaviour was chosen, I always thought that std::function is C++ equivalent of raw function pointer, apparently it does much more. Thanks for explanation.