# Is it a good practice to have a use a template in a derived class? C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently new to C++ in the working world (learnt C++ academically). This is my first job where C++ is the base requirement.

May I ask -

1. When do I use a template for a class?
2. Is there any ideal or good practices that uses a template in a derived class, where the base class does not inherit any templates?

For example:

```
class Base {};

<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {};
```

The reason why I need to inherit from a base is because I need to store objects where it can be referenced from the base, and thereafter have a common factory method where I can pull information out.

Comment: What do you need the template for?

Comment: Yes it can be a totally valid design, specialy if you want a collection of Base instances (e.g. in a vector). I use it a lot, though mostly I only let Base be an abstract base class (interface) without putting logic in it.

Comment: Basically, you are asking one single question: when do we use template. In a word, use template when you have to regard a type as a changeable stuff.

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice in some cases. A typical use case is _type erasure_. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815953/580083. Another one may be _CRTP_ with a single common base, such as shown here: https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/.

Comment: A non-templated base can be useful for collecting members that don't depend on T. This way all `Derived<T>`s can use the common code.