# C++ Is passing a tempoary object to a class holding a reference to that object valid C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, stack

Found on this blog

http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html

```
class Cow;

template <typename T>
class AnimalWrapper : public MyAnimal
{
    const T &m_animal;

public:
    AnimalWrapper(const T &animal)
        : m_animal(animal)
    { }
};

MyAnimal* animal = new AnimalWrapper(Cow());
```

Is this valid C++? I believe it will compile, but on seeing this immediatly thought undefined behaviour.

I thought that references were implemented like pointers, however I am now questioning this.

In my mind, it would be like doing this:

```
int *p = nullptr;
{
    int temp;
    p = &temp;
}
cout << *p << endl; // undefined behaviour, stack allocated temporary object "temp" is no longer on the stack
```

As far as I can see, there are two possibilities.

- I am wrong, and references do not exactly behave like pointers
- The code in this blog produces undefined behaviour

Can anyone enlighten me? If this is valid C++, then why?

Comment: Don't think of a reference as a pointer.  A reference is an alias to an object, the standard doesn't even require a reference to take up any space.

Comment: For future reference: Code in the linked blog is wrong. I was correct in my suspicions. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NathanOliver does it require a pointer to take up any space?

Comment: Yes.  A pointer is an object, and as such it needs to take up at least one byte of space.