# How to define a pointer to the template type

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T t;
};
```

In the other struct I would like to define a pointer to the struct A:

```
struct B
{
    //A* a;
};
```

A specific type for object of type A will be known during object A creation. How to define a pointer to the template type inside struct B ?

Comment: Either `B` also needs to be a template with the same type `T` or you need type erasure. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815513/what-is-type-erasure-in-c

Comment: `A<int>* a`  / `template <typename T> struct B { A<T>* a; };`

Comment: I don't want use template for struct B so the type erasure is the only way to solve the above issue.

Comment: @Irbis I think this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: `struct B { void* a; };` pointer other than a void pointer can be assigned pointers pointers to arbitary structs and template instantiations are entirely unrelated in this regard...

Answer (score 6):

> How to define a pointer to the template type?

A class template is not a type so you can't have pointers to them. You need to instantiate the class template in order to get a class based on the template and then you can make pointers to instances of that class.

Example:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct B
{
    A<T>* a;
};
```

Here `B<int>` would hold a pointer to `A<int>`. The unrelated class `B<double>` would hold a pointer to an `A<double>` etc.

---

An alternative could be to just store the pointer in a `std::any` and cast when needed:

```cpp
#include <any>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    T t;
};

struct B {
    template<class T>
    void store(A<T>& o) {
        a = &o;
    }

    template<class T>
    A<T>& get() {
        return *std::any_cast<A<T>*>(a);
    }

    std::any a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    
    A<int> ai;
    
    b.store(ai);

    auto& aref = b.get<int>();
}
```

Comment: @MikeVine A good question indeed. Updated.