# How to comprehend that the type of `std::function` depends solely on its call signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

As per the documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/), which says that:

> Class that can wrap any kind of callable element (such as functions
>   and function objects) into a copyable object, and whose type depends
>   solely on its call signature (and not on the callable element type
>   itself).

How to comprehend that the type of `std::function` depends solely on its call signature(and not on the callable element type itself)? Could somebody make it clear by giving some simple examples?I would be greatful to have some help with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template type effectively denotes a function signature (excluding name of course).

`std::function<bool(Bar const&, Foo const&)>`

Can hold a functor, member function pointer, function pointer or lambda. But the callable must have the `bool (Bar const&, Foo const&)` signature.

```
class Foo {};
class Bar {};
class FunctorEx
{
  public:
    bool operator()(Bar const&, Foo const&)
    {
        return true;
    }
} FunctorExInst;

class MemFunction
{
  public:
    bool MemFunctionEx(Bar const&, Foo const&)
    {
        return true;
    }
} MemFunctionInst;

bool FunctionEx(Bar const&, Foo const&)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    auto LambdaEx = [] (Bar const&, Foo const&) -> bool
    {
        return true;
    };

    std::function<bool(Bar const&, Foo const&)> exFunctionVar;
    exFunctionVar = std::bind(&MemFunction::MemFunctionEx, &MemFunctionInst, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    exFunctionVar = FunctorExInst;
    exFunctionVar = FunctionEx;
    exFunctionVar = LambdaEx;
}
```

Despite `MemFunctionInst`, `FunctorExInst`, `FunctionEx`, `LambdaEx` all being of different types, they can all be assigned to the same `std::function` variable due to a technique called [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques).

Comment: Thank you so much.I think i completly understand how to use `std::function` with your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of callable's, namely functions and functors.  `std::function` was designed to not mater which of those you give to it, for example, lets consider a `std::function <void()>`.  Here we say the function is one that return nothing and takes nothing, which means that

```
void foo() {}
auto bar = []{};
struct { void operator()(){} } baz;
```

are all things that can be assigned to it, even though they are all different types.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.One more question, what are "functors"?Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Functors are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: I see.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

These two "callable elements" have the same call signatures (namely, `int(float)`), even though they have different types:

```cpp
struct Functor {
  int operator()(float arg) {
    ...
  }
};

int function(float arg) {
  ...
}
```

This means you can use the same `std::function` type to represent either of them:

```cpp
std::function<int(float)> f;
f = Functor();
f = function;
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.You example is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If we forget all gory details, then the important method of `std::function` is `operator()`.

Consider you write a wrapper for callables with signature `double (int,int)`, then the wrapper will be something similar to:

```
struct example_wrapper {
     double operator()(int a,int b) { return 42; }
};
```

The details I left out is what enables you to make `std::function` wrap any kind of callable. If the callables have the same signature, then the wrapper can have the exact same public interface (ie it is the same type). If the callables have different signature, the wrapper needs a different public interface (ie it is a different type).

Comment: Thank you.If i understand you correctly, i think the `std::function` may be implemented like this.Am i right?

Comment: @sunshilong369 not sure what you mean. Actually I left out all implementation and only concentrated on the part that explains why same signature is same `std::function` type.

Answer (score 1):

This means simply that the type of the callable stored in `std::function` does not impact the type of `std::function` itself, only the function signature does.

This can for example be implemented as such non-optimized:

```
template<class F, class Ret, class... Args>
Ret invoke_functor(void* func, Args&& ...args)
{
    return (*reinterpret_cast<F*>(f))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class Ret, class... Args>
Ret invoke_function(void* func, Args&& ...args)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Ret(*)(Args...)>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args...);
}

template<class Ret, class... Args> //wrong but close enough
class function
{
public:
    template<class Functor>
    function(Functor&& f) :
        m_func(new Functor(f)), //leak
        m_invoke(&invoke_functor<Functor, Ret, Args...>)
    { }

    function(Ret(*ptr)(Args...)) :
         m_func(ptr),
         m_invoke(&invoke_function<Ret, Args...>)
    { }

     Ret
     operator()(const Args& ...args)
     {
          return m_invoke(m_func, args);
     }

private:
    void* m_func;
    Ret(*m_invoke)(void*, Args...);
}
```

Here `std::function` can be created from both functions and callable structures as shown by the other answers.

Comment: Thank you so much.Though i could not completly understand the code now, i would go out my way to comprehend it.