# Any type of value in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've go the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > > SCHEMA;

int main() {
    SCHEMA tables;

    // Schema table
    tables["table_name"]["row_id"]["field_name"] = "value";
}
```

I want to modify the **typedef** to have a "row_id" as a numeric index and value of any type (kind of auto detecting). What should I do to achieve something like this?

```
tables["table1"][0]["field1"] = "value of any type";
```

Comment: For the `any type` part, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208959/c-variant

Answer (score 1):

Numeric index is easy, just replace `std::string` with `int`.   "Value of any type" can be tricky to get right C++, and can lead to problem if not done carefully.  You could use `void *` (bad) or a `union` (ok), but a better option would probably be some variant implementation, e.g. [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html), so the `typedef` would read, for example:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<int, std::map<std::string, boost::variant<int, std::string> > > > SCHEMA;
```

Comment: Boost is not available on school machine. Could you give an example of union based on my code?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the Internet explaining how to use a union, but really I would either use boost::variant or create my own. Union might do the job, but it's not really the right tool.