# Accept and identify any type of input C++

Tags: c++, validation, input

I'm trying to write a simple C++ program that creates a linked list. I would like to make this list be able to store any type of data in its container. However, I realised that my main problem is being able to accept any type of input and storing it. For example, if the variable `std::cin` stores to is of type string, only strings will be accepted, and this variable must be defined before program compilation.

My question is: is there any way to accept any type of input with a `std::cin` (or any other input method) and then call certain functions depending on the input's type?

Something along the logic of...

```
cin >> data

if (data.type == string)
{
    cout << "data's type: string"
}

if (data.type == int)
{
    cout << "data's type: int"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Variant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208959/c-variant)

Comment: Read as a string, try to convert to an integer, if it succeeds (and all of the string was consumed in the conversion) then you had an integer, else it's a string. I answered this some time ago, but can't seem to find my own answer for a duplicate.

Comment: Overload a function to take different types.Why not try that? Just have the body of each overload printing out each type that is given to the function.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is (mostly) **statically typed**. That is, the types of variables have to be known at compile time and cannot change at runtime, e.g. depending on some user input.

The one exception to this rule are polymorphic classes: When you have a base class with some `virtual` member function, then there will be a way (most likely a pointer as a member of all instances of that class) to distinguish between sub classes of that class (and itself):

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
struct SubA : public Base {};
struct SubB : public Base {};

// ...

Base const & instance = SubA{};
try {
  SubA const & as_subA = dynamic_cast<SubA const &>(instance);
  // The instance is a SubA, so the code following here will be run.
} catch (std::bad_cast const &) { /* handle that somehow */ }
```

Using this mechanism, or preferably the virtual function itself, you can have different behavior depending on the **dynamic type** of an instance, which is only known at run time.

C++ being a flexible language, you can - of course - also implement something similar on your own:

```
struct Thing {
  enum class Type {
    Integer, String, Vector
  } type;
  union {
    int integer;
    std::string string;
    std::vector<int> vector;
  } data;
  // Plus a lot of work in constructors, destructor and assignment, see rule of 5
};
```

Using something like this allows you to have objects with a "type" of dynamic nature, and are able to do different things depending on what type the object actually has at run time.

But of course you don't need to write that on your own ([though its not that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32041381/1116364)), there are a lot of implementations like for example [`boost::any`](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.any) and [`boost::variant`](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.variant).