# mixing different vector<*> into one vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Suppose there is an object which contains some data members, like this:

```
class MyObject {
   int age;
   string name;
   bool is_cool;
   …

   get(string member_name);  // returns the value of member
};
```

and now there is a `MyIterator` object by which I could iterate over all the `MyObject`, and during which I want to get some of the data members of `MyObject`, like the pseudo code below:

```
get_members(vector<string> member_names, vector<*> &output) {
  MyIterator it;
  while (it.next_myobject()) {
    for (name in member_names) {
       output.push_back(it.get(name))
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is, I don’t know how I could implement this idea, but if I only get 1 data member, I know how to implement this by defining a template function, like this:

```
template <typename T>
get_member(string member_name, vector<T> &output) {
  MyIterator it;
  while (it.next_myobject()) {
    output.push_back(it.get<T>(member_name));
  }
}
```

Give me some help :-)

Comment: You are looking for a _variant_ pattern.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/208968/1553090

Comment: Not everyone who isn't male is female. Some people are born with ambiguous organs. Help include them in society by reflecting this in your code.

Comment: Why do you need such a vector? What would you do with it?

Comment: @n.m. , it's a long story

Comment: Well, chances are, it's a needlessly long story. But whatever works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work out what static type you're going to store in the output vector, given you have multiple logical data types.  [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) (which uses RTTI so you can test for specific types later), and [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) (which is a *discriminated union* able to store any of a set list of types) are reasonable choices.  If you don't want to use boost, you can at least refer to their documentation to understand the concepts, then look at implementing something minimal and similar, though I'd recommend avoiding that as you'll waste time writing/debugging it....

If your needs are *really* simple, you may be able to settle for string representations of all the values (i.e. `std::vector<std::string>& output`, use a `std::istringstream` to get a representation of an arbitrary type).